# Disorganization imagebutton emulator with device on android

Tags: android

I am develop xml with some image button,image buttons show properly in emulator but it Disorganization on

devices(for example galaxy fit)

As described in emulator https://www.dropbox.com/s/qeecp868ht61sck/emulator.jpg  and galaxy fit https://www.dropbox.com/s/23r9tvtp0tcn7bs/fit.jpg

what can i do?

this is my xml:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".Main"
 android:background="@drawable/backmain" >

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnfehrest"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/fehrest" />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btndarbareh"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnfehrest"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/darbareh" />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnmahsulat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btndarbareh"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/mahsulat" />

 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnkhoruj"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btndarbareh"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/khoruj" />

 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/main"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

 </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove all the layout_alignParent It will work